# How can I simplify $\frac{n\%2}{2} - \frac{(n-1)\%2}{2} $?

Tags: calculus

given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, how can i simplify this expression?
$$\frac{n\%2}{2} - \frac{(n-1)\%2}{2} $$
while $\%$ is modulo 2.

---

I thought that it's:
$$\frac{n\%2}{2} - \frac{(n-1)\%2}{2} = \frac{n\%2-(n-1)\%2}{2} = \frac{(n-n+1)\%2}{2}=\frac{1}{2} $$
But for example, it's not correct for $n=2$..
It's look like $\frac{1}{2}$ for odd numbers, and $-\frac{1}{2}$ for even numbers, but I don't understand where is the problem in my way.

Comment: In general $(a \mod 2) - (b\mod 2)\not= (a-b \mod 2)$, but $(a \mod 2) - (b\mod 2) \equiv (a-b) \mod 2$. The problem lies there. Try to see what goes wrong. 
Your intuition is good, you will get 1/2 for odd and -1/2 for even.

Comment: @Kolja So it's will be correct to say that it's equal to $\frac{1}{2} mod 2$?

Comment: No. Try even and odd cases. The result will be different for both.

Comment: $\mod 2$ is not an operation and it is wrong to think of it as such $5 \mod 3$ does *not* equal $2$.  Instead $5$ and $2$ have something in common and can be considered equivalent for the purpose of arithmetic modulo $3$.  So we say $2 \equiv 5 \mod 3$.  Note $\equiv$ is not $=$.  And note we can say $5 \equiv 2 \mod 3$ as well.  The $\mod 3$ isn't actually operating on just the $2$ or the $5$ but on the entire concept of doing arithmetic.

Comment: I'm guessing they're just looking for something like (-1)^(n-1)*(1/2)

Answer (score 1):

There's sometimes confusions between the two uses of "mod".  The one you're using here is not the equivalence relation, but a unary operation.  The calculation in your numerator would be valid for the equivalence relation.  But here, where the output is either $0$ or $1$ you can't really do this:

$$n\%2 +(n-1)\%2 = (n-n+1)\%2.$$

To see this do, suppose $n$ is even and try to distribute your operation:

$$1=(n-1)\%2 = n\%2 -1 \%2 = 0 -1.$$

Answer (score 0):

The thing the notice is $1\%2 = (-1)\%2$ so it doesn't "really matter".

.... except if the question is asking abut making fractions, the conventions of what $\%$ is used for a tossed out the window.

There are three ways to interpret $a \% c$.

1).  $a \% c$ is the remainder $r$ that you get when you divide $c$ into $a$.  It is a number that is equal or greater than $0$ but less than $c$ i.e $0 \le r < c$.  There is *one* precise value. $a\%c = r$

2).  $a \%c$ can be any number that has the same remainder as $a$ does when $c$ is divided into it.  It will either be the remainder $r$ or $r$ plus some multiple of $c$.   There is one value but it's up to you to choose which one you want. $a\%c = r \pm kc$.

3) $a\%c$ actually represents a set of numbers that all have the same remainder as $a$ does when divided by $c$.  So $a \% c= \{...., r-2c, r-c, r, r+c , r+2c ....\} = \{a + kc| k \in \mathbb Z\}$.

If we interpret it as 2) and 3) then $a \% c + b\% c  = (a+b)\%c$.

But if we interpret it as 1) then $(a \% c) + (b\%c)\ne (a+b)\%c$.  If $a\%c = r$ and $b+c = s$ and $r + s \ge c$ then $(a\%c) + (b\%c) = r+s = (r+s)\%c + c$.

However $[(a\%c) + (b\%c)]\%c= (a+b)\%c$.

And $(a\%c) + (b\%c) = $ either $(a+b)\%c$ or $(a+b)\%c - c$.

And $(a\%c) - (b\%c) = (a-b)%c$ or it equals $(a-b) - c$

So $n\% c - (n-1)%c$ equals either $(n - (n-1))%c = 1$ or $(n-(n-1))%c - 2 = 1-2=1$.

It equals $1$ if $n\%2 > (n-1)%2$ and it equal $n-(n-1)%-2$ if $(n-1)\%2 > n\%2$.

In other words:  If $n$ is odd then $n\% 2 = 1$ and $(n-1)\%2 = 0$ and $n\%n-(n-1)\% n = 1$.  If $n$ is even then $n\%2 = 0$ and $(n-1)\%2 = 1$ and $n\%n - (n-1)\%n = 0-1 = -1$.

But the *usually* doesn't matter a $-1\% 2 = 1 \% 2$ and *usually* we are the entire purpose of taking $\%$ as an operation is not to actually get single numbers but to do 3) above and to get *properties* and classes of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct, it's the sequence that is ${\frac{1}{2}}$ for all odd natural numbers and ${-\frac{1}{2}}$ for all even natural numbers. Knowing the psychology of most teachers and textbooks, I'm guessing by "simplify" they're looking for something like this:

$${(-1)^{n-1}*\frac{1}{2}}$$